# Postgresql - Date comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query from pgAdmin3 against my postgresql database. I am wondering why it is returning values but all expected values. The query is:

```
SELECT P.SURNAME, 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS GRANTDATE,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.REVOKEDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS REVOKEDATE, 
       SFE.feedname  
FROM   SYS_FEED SFE,
       PRINCIPLE P
WHERE  SFE.USERID = P.ID   
AND    to_date(GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= to_date('Nov-2006','Mon-YYYY')
```

The GRANTDATE column is type date and contains values in the format 2006-09-04. I want to return all rows where the GRANTDATE is less than or equal to the month-year provided. The problem i have is that it returns all the "less than" matching rows but does not return the "equals to" rows. So Jan-2006 to Oct-2006 is there but not Nov-2006.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: You don't need the cast to do the comparison.

Comment: i did try running the query with Dec-2006 and the Nov-2006 dataset appears but not the Dec-2006 dataset.

Comment: When the GRANTDATE column is of type date there is no need to do to_date(GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'). It will only slow things down as it first has to turn GRANTDATE into a string and then convert it back again. As for the solution see Igor's answer.

Comment: Contradicting: `The GRANTDATE column is type date and contains values in the format 2006-09-04.` If the column is of type `date`, it doesn't "have" a format. If it "has" a format, it's not a `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT P.SURNAME, 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS GRANTDATE,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.REVOKEDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS REVOKEDATE, 
       SFE.feedname  
FROM   SYS_FEED SFE,
       PRINCIPLE P
WHERE  SFE.USERID = P.ID   
AND    to_date(GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < (to_date('Nov-2006','Mon-YYYY') + interval '1 month');
```

The problem: When you do `to_date('Nov-2006','Mon-YYYY')` you get the `2006-11-01`. So the only date, that will be equal to `to_date('Nov-2006','Mon-YYYY')` is `2006-11-01`, not the whole month.

Edit. The other way:

```
SELECT P.SURNAME, 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS GRANTDATE,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SFE.REVOKEDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD Mon YY') AS REVOKEDATE, 
       SFE.feedname  
FROM   SYS_FEED SFE,
       PRINCIPLE P
WHERE  SFE.USERID = P.ID   
AND    date_trunc('month', to_date(GRANTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')) <= to_date('Nov-2006','Mon-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 2):

As Erwin stated: dates have no format. Also: there is no need to do all the excessive casting of dates to and from characters. 
Besides: even for the final query result, you could do a `SET datestyle;` (for the most common styles in use), and avoid all the excessive formatting.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE SYS_FEED
        ( USERID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , GRANTDATE DATE NOT NULL
        , REVOKEDATE DATE NOT NULL
        , feedname varchar
        );
INSERT INTO SYS_FEED(USERID, GRANTDATE, REVOKEDATE, feedname)
SELECT sv
        , date('2005-01-01') + sv
        , date('2006-01-01') + sv
        , 'silent_' || sv::text
FROM generate_series( 1,1000) sv
        ;
CREATE TABLE PRINCIPLE
        ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , SURNAME varchar
        );
INSERT INTO PRINCIPLE(ID,SURNAME)
SELECT val
        , 'SHOUT_' || val::text
FROM generate_series( 1,1000) val
        ;

DELETE FROM SYS_FEED WHERE random() < 0.9;
DELETE FROM PRINCIPLE WHERE random() < 0.9;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT P.SURNAME
       , to_char(SFE.GRANTDATE, 'DD Mon YY') AS GRANTDATE
       , to_char(SFE.REVOKEDATE, 'DD Mon YY') AS REVOKEDATE
       , SFE.feedname AS DONTSHOUTNAME
FROM    SYS_FEED SFE
JOIN    PRINCIPLE P ON SFE.USERID = P.ID
WHERE   GRANTDATE < '2006-12-01'
        ;
```

RESULT:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "sys_feed_pkey" for table "sys_feed"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1000
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "principle_pkey" for table "principle"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1000
DELETE 901
DELETE 904
  surname  | grantdate | revokedate | dontshoutname 
-----------+-----------+------------+---------------
 SHOUT_53  | 23 Feb 05 | 23 Feb 06  | silent_53
 SHOUT_173 | 23 Jun 05 | 23 Jun 06  | silent_173
 SHOUT_308 | 05 Nov 05 | 05 Nov 06  | silent_308
 SHOUT_337 | 04 Dec 05 | 04 Dec 06  | silent_337
 SHOUT_531 | 16 Jun 06 | 16 Jun 07  | silent_531
 SHOUT_543 | 28 Jun 06 | 28 Jun 07  | silent_543
 SHOUT_566 | 21 Jul 06 | 21 Jul 07  | silent_566
(7 rows)
```